# Executing a powershell script from another script with $PSScriptRoot?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm wondering what I'm missing here. I have a powershell script that calls another script with some parameters to execute as a way to keep things tidy. Here is what works:

```
C:\Scripts\Project\coolscript.ps1 -projname 'my.project' -domain 'work'
```

I want others to be able to use this script without having to change anything, so I thought I could make the path relative instead of the full one starting from C: so I thought I could execute the script like this:

```
$pathname = $PSScriptRoot + '\coolscript.ps1' 
$pathname -projname 'my.project' -domain 'work'
```

however I get an error that says 'unexpected token in expression or statement for everything after $pathname

ANy ideas what I'm missing? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-) (`&`) as follows:

```
& $pathname -projname 'my.project' -domain 'work'
```

> **Call operator &**
>
> *Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are
>   stored in variables and represented by strings or script blocks. The
>   call operator executes in a child scope. For more about scopes, see
>   [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7).*